# How do I setup a Python script to run multiple hours each day using Google Cloud job cloud scheduler / cron jobs using AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to have a Python script run each day, triggered in the morning at 9am and killed around 5pm (i.e. during trading hours). I have seen multiple posts about using Google Cron jobs but have not found a clear explanation on how to set this up. I uploaded my script into a Google Bucket in and ran using a Google VM successfully, so it's just a matter of automating.

I thought of potentially creating a function and running that but Google cloud functions timeout after 9 minutes apparently. I believe what I need to do is setup the script in an AppEngine but I have not found great resources on how to do this for a simple setup. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You want it to run continuously for 8 hours? What is it doing? If you can give us some more details we can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Dustin, it's a day trading algorithm that uses an async handler to track several stock indices, with realtime trading data via the Polygon API. Here's the base code I used: https://github.com/alpacahq/Momentum-Trading-Example.git

Answer (score 0):

If you run it with a Google VM, you could use the VM cron to activate the job.
Adding something like this with `crontab -e`

`09 00 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/python script.py`

And you could schedule the instance to start a few minutes before 9 using and shutdown at 5. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule#gcloud_2).

If you want to go full serverless, you could put the algorithm in a container and use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python), triggering with [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push).